# NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass): with jquery-datatables-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying to get filtering working on jquery-datatables by following these [instructions](http://www.enten-itc.ch/fr/posts/add-a-filter-form-to-a-ruby-on-rails-server-side-processing-datatable).

Before I added the filters it was returning the json needed by datatables without any issue but now I'm getting the above error and cannot identify the issue.

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        @sbcons = Subcontractor.scoped
        filters = params[:filter]
        @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].nil? or filters[:type].blank?
        @sbcons = @sbcons.where(cscs_card: filters[:cscs]) unless filters[:cscs].nil? or filters[:cscs].blank?
        @sbcons = @sbcons.where(approved_status: filters[:approved]) unless filters[:approved].nil? or filters[:approved].blank?
        render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
      end
    end
  end

<% provide(:title, 'All Subcontractors') %>
<h1>Subcontractors List</h1>
<div class="filter">
  <%= form_tag(method: :get, id: "filter_form") do %>
    <%= label_tag :sbcon_type, "Type" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[type]", options_for_select([[],["Labour Only"], ["Specialist"], ["Both"]]) %>
    <%= label_tag :cscs_card, "CSCS" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[cscs]", options_for_select([[],["Yes"], ["No"]]) %>
    <%= label_tag :approved_status, "Approved Status" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[status]", options_for_select([[],["Approved"], ["Not Approved"]]) %> <br>
    <%= link_to "Filter", '#', id: "filterbutton", class: "btn btn-mini" %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
</div>
<table id="subcontractors" class="table table-condensed table-hover display" data-source="<%= subcontractors_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Contact Number</th>
      <th>CSCS</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Scotland</th>
      <th>NE England</th>
      <th>NW England</th>
      <th>Midlands</th>
      <th>SE England</th>
      <th>SW England</th>
      <th>London</th>
      <th>Wales</th>
      <th>Operatives</th>
      <th>Product Liability</th>
      <th>Employer Liability</th>
      <th>Public Liability</th>
      <th>Contractors All Risk</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= javascript_tag do %> 
  $('#filterbutton').click(function (){
    $('#subcontractors').dataTable().fnDraw();
  });
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:31:in`block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:26:in `index'

Line 31: @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].nil? or filters[:type].blank?

Line 26: respond_to do |format|

Comment: can you post the stack trace , at which line it says the error

Comment: Also, `filters[:type].blank?` will test for `.nil?` too: `nil.blank? #=> true` (and `.present?` is the opposite of `.blank?`)

Comment: I've updated the question with the trace and thanks for the information about the .nils being extraneous.

Comment: `filters` is nil on line 31.

Comment: shouldn't the unless filters[:type].nil? prevent that?

Comment: No, but `filters.nil?` will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all of the business logic out of and above the `respond_to` block. That block should only contain code necessary for rendering views.

Also, you don't need both `.nil?` and `.blank?` conditionals. `.blank?` checks for nil anyway.

Check if `filters` is nil once before doing any further setting. Use a conditional block as shown.

Your index action should look like this:

```
def index
  @sbcons = Subcontractor.scoped
  if filters = params[:filter]
    @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].blank?
    @sbcons = @sbcons.where(cscs_card: filters[:cscs]) unless filters[:cscs].blank?
    @sbcons = @sbcons.where(approved_status: filters[:approved]) unless filters[:approved].blank?
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
    end
  end
end
```

This code is still far from optimized, but it should satisfy the question.

Comment: That's fixed it unfortunately now render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons) is throwing ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1))